# Recorrer lista de objetos dinámico en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Vengo de javascript y quisiera saber de que manera puedo recorrer ese array que en python se le conoce como list.

```
"dispatches_types": [
  {
    "status_id": 2
  },
  {
    "status_id": 1
  },
  {
    "status_id": 1
  },
  {
    "status_id": 1
  },
  {
    "status_id": 2
  }
 ]
```

El problema que tengo es que quiero agregar un contador que aumente cuando el `status_id` sea **1** pero esto es dinamico ya que aveces puede traer ese status y aveces no. Hasta aveces puede traer la lista vacía.

Hasta el momento estoy intentado de esta manera:

```
    cont = 0
    if len(dispatch_types) > 0:
        for status1 in dispatch_types:
            if 1 in status1:
                cont +=1
    else:
        cont = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas más "phytonicas, o al menos que aprovechan mejor las herramientas del lenguaje, también colateralmente suelen ser más sencillas de leer. En primer lugar, tu ejemplo es un diccionario cuyo clave `"dispatches_types"` contiene una lista de otros diccionarios. Algo así:

```
d = {
  "dispatches_types": [
     {"status_id": 2},
     {"status_id": 1},
     {"status_id": 1},
     {"status_id": 1},
     {"status_id": 2}
 ]
}
```

Lo que buscas es determinar cuantos `status_id == 1` hay en la lista mencionada. Una forma es la siguiente:

```
print(sum([1 for e in d["dispatches_types"] if e["status_id"]==1]))

3
```

- En primer lugar, con `[1 for e in d["dispatches_types"] if e["status_id"]==1]` usamos una comprensión de listas para construir una nueva lista con un valor `1` por cada vez que tengamos `status_id == 1`
- Y con [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) simplemente sumamos la lista.
- Esta forma es consistente con una lista vacía o con `status_id == 1` inexistentes, en ambos casos se retornará `0`

También. puede resultarte interesante, el uso de la clase [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(e["status_id"] for e in d["dispatches_types"]))

Counter({1: 3, 2: 2})
```

El `Counter` te retornará a partir de la lista `e["status_id"] for e in d["dispatches_types"]`. un objeto tipo diccionario, con las ocurrencias por cada `status_id`

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio Moracho. Tu solución y explicación son muy buenas :D

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de esta manera pero aun sigo teniendo dudas:

```
        cont = 0
        if len(dispatch_types) > 0:
            for status1 in dispatch_types:
                if status1["status_id"] == 1:
                    cont +=1
                    print(cont)
        else:
            cont = 0
            print(cont)
```